# CMake static link Qt5

Tags: cmake, static-linking, qt5, mingw32

I've been developing a program with Qt5 on Linux without a problem, now I'm trying to compile it on Windows using CMake (with Qt5CoreConfig.cmake, etc.) and mingw32.
Everything works OK, except that I don't know how to static link my project.

This is how I add Qt5 to my project:

```
foreach(lib Qt5Core Qt5Widgets Qt5Gui Qt5Xml)
    find_package(${lib} REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${${lib}_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    list(APPEND LIBS ${${lib}_LIBRARIES})
    add_definitions(${${lib}_DEFINITIONS})
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${${lib}_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
endforeach(lib)
```

What should I do to make it static?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot build a static application with the windows version installed from the QT web site. You need to compile a windows binary from source with -static option enabled.